# Merge a list of json files containing JSON arrays

Tags: json, jq

I have a list of json files like:

```
file1.json
[
  {obj1}
]

file2.json
[
  {obj2}
]
```

and I want to merge them all into one file:

```
[
  {obj1},
  {obj2}
]
```

How can I achieve this using jq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by invoking `jq` two times like this:

```
jq -c '.[]' *.json | jq -s
```

#### How it works

`*.json` is evaluated by the shell and replaced with the list of matching files. `jq` gets the names of all JSON files in the current directory as arguments. It reads them one by one and runs the program `.[]` on the JSONs they contain.

Each JSON file contains an array. `.[]` extracts the items from the array and dumps them.
`-c` tells `jq` to output each value (the items extracted by `.[]`) on a single line.

The output of the first `jq` command is composed of one line for each object from the arrays stored in the input files.

This output is then fed to the second `jq` command whose `-s` argument tells it to read everything (it normally reads one JSON at a time) and put all the objects it decodes from the input JSONs into an array. This is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following :

```
jq -s 'add' file1.json file2.json
```

Using `-s`lurp mode makes `jq` handle multiple inputs in a single pass, concatenating them into an array that contains your two arrays. We can merge them into a single one by transforming the input array with the `add` filter which yields the sum of each element as if using `+`; using it on arrays returns a single array with all the elements of both arrays.